# What is the shortcodes_att function for in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, refactoring

I'm wondering what is the purpose of the function: [shortcode_atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts)

Because it's possible to write:

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'Title' => 'Title'
), $atts );
```

or without using this function:

```
$a = $atts['Title'] ? $atts['Title'] : "";
```

So I would like to know when I should use the shortcode_atts function?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress contains lots of filters to allow various plugins to do things like adjust or localize things.

The `shortcode_atts()` function applies a filter. Just fiddling with an array does not.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts#Change_Log

Also, sometimes the core developers change data structures. If you use the functions, your software won't break when they do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here simple the function **shortcode_atts** used is to overwrite the shortcode parameter argument that passed.
2. if you passing argument through *shortcode* then it will automatically apply the shortcode_atts array **variable key** with argument/parameter  you passed with shortcode.

   3. it will overwrite the function that associate with shortcode eg.

> [new_shortcode id='123']

);

```
        function do_task(){
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(id=>''), 'new_shortcode');

        }
        ?>
```